# Shell script: know when there is redirected input

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I am trying to figure out a way for a shell script to know when some input has been redirected in order to run a python script with different command line args. My shell script is called `P2` and the possible invocations need to be (unfortunately no flexibility on this):

```
1. P2
2. P2 < someFile
3. P2 someFile
```

and ideally, the shell script pseudocode would work like this:

```
if argCount == 2:
  run (python P2.py someFile)
else:
  if inputWasRedirected: **********_issue is here_**********
    run (python P2.py < someFile)
  else:
    run (python P2.py)
```

Any and all help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't.  Try as hard as possible to avoid this.  There are numerous examples of common programs that behave differently when their input comes from a tty than they do when their input comes from a regular file, but there are zero examples of this behavior being innocuous, helpful, or not broken.  If you want to read from a tty or from a user, then implement code which does that.  Do not anticipate that reading from stdin will be reading from a tty or a user, and do not try to reduce the code required to read from a tty by instead reading from stdin.  Just don't.

Comment: What do you even mean by "redirected"?  If someone writes a script that calls `P2` with a line like `P2 path` (1 argument, and no explicit redirection), but that script is called as `echo foo | cmd` or `< path cmd`, is the input to `P2` redirected?  Probably you mean you want to detect if `P2`'s input is a tty (or a pty) or a pipe or a regular file.

Comment: `[ -t ... ]` lets you check whether a file handle is connected to a terminal. This is not exactly what you are asking, but probably what you want, and a fairly common duplicate.

Comment: Why would you need a shell script wrapper for this, though? This should be easy to do in Python directly.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Thanks for your input. Unfortunately, I didn't have a choice in these invocations. They were directed by my professor.

Comment: @tripleee Thank you for your help, I ended up using your suggestion. I need a wrapper for this because my teacher is too lazy to type ```python P2.py``` and wants to just type ```P2```. I initially implemented it in python, but got a zero :(

Comment: Wanting to type the executable name instead of invoking it via python is not "laziness", it's the correct way to do things.  But it has nothing to do with whether the input stream is a tty or a pipe or regular file.  If your python code is a module that is intended to be imported, name it with a `.py` suffix and do not make it executable.  If your code is a script intended to be executed, don't name it with a `.py` suffix, make it executable, and give it the proper shebang.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
#!/bin/sh

if test -n "$1"; then
    echo "Your input is : $1";
elif test ! -t 0; then
    echo "Read from stdin"
    input=$(cat)
    echo your input is :  $input;
else
    echo "No data provided..."
fi
```

As you can see [Check if no command line arguments and STDIN is empty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/484630/check-if-no-command-line-arguments-and-stdin-is-empty), the major tricks are as follow:

- Detecting that you have an argument is done through the `test -n $1` which is checking if a first argument exists.
- Then, checking if stdin is not open on the terminal (because it is piped to a file) is done with `test ! -t 0` (check if the file descriptor zero (aka stdin) is not open).
- And, finally, everything else fall in the last case (No data provided...).

Answer (score 0):

If the python script is written properly, you don't need to handle anything. Just pass the script arguments (`"$@"`) to python:

```
#!/bin/sh
python P2.py "$@"
```

`"$@"` expands to all arguments given to the shell script (including expanding to nothing if no arguments given).

Python also inherits any stdin redirection of the shell.

It's up to the python script to prefer file arguments over stdin (conventional behaviour).

Eg. `test`, using cat instead of python:

```
#!/bin/sh
cat "$@"
```

- For `./test a b < c`, files `a` and `b` are printed.
- For `./test < c` file `c` is printed.
- For `./test`, cat reads input from the terminal.